# How Can I find a Null Value within a number?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, domo

I'm using the BI tool **Domo**, which uses Amazon Red Shift. I have a dataset that runs nightly using Zendesk data.

I'm getting this error:

```
OnboardFlowExecution(2794) data flow execution id 
(724670342c4c48a9a61e7a617e6462c1) failed: 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
```

I've researched the error and I am under the impression that somewhere in the data set a `Number` Column has data it doesn't like and is wreaking havoc with my downstream process.

How do I find the offending column/row ?

Comment: I have no hands-on experience with Domo so take this with a grain of salt... but this appears to be your BI Tool breaking because of improper data input from the backend. BI Tools typically reside directly on a database or use proprietary datamarts (universes, cubes, etc..) fed by a database through an admin ETL process. Your best bet is going to be to identify any available log files to better track down which table is failing and then going directly into the backend database to check your process assumptions vs. the data actually present. Tedious, i know, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: I agree with you that it is the BI Tool.  But any help I to identify the offending column and field will go a long way.  Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, no one here is going to be able to help you with the specifics you are looking for because they would need full access to your system to identify the issue. I can tell you from your java.lang.NumberFormatException (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) that you appear to be trying to convert a null value to a number. If I had to guess, it is probably during an ETL process to convert the data for end users so you should contact your DBA or the BI Admin that created your Datamarts to search through failure logs.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon RedShift is expecting a string value in the column but receiving 'null' values instead. Hence, it's throwing an exception (a kind of error).

Add a transform to the input dataset to handle the null exception. We've previously used NVL function in RedShift to replace null values with something else.

E.g. Your transform could be:

Select employee_id, NVL(emp_first_name, 'No Name') from employees;

The NVL function will replace all the null values in the 'emp_first_name' column with 'No Name'

Comment: You can also use the inbuilt Domo ETL to remove/replace nulls with something else.